# setBackButtonBackgroundImage not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am simply trying to change the back button icon in the `UINavigationBar` to a custom image so it matches all the rest of the icons used, however I have approached this two different ways.

One setting the back image an mask image in the `UINavigationController` within the storyboard inspector to the image, which resulted in the image not being in line with the title or `rightBarItem`.

[image]

Another method I have tried is `setBackButtonBackgroundImage` within the `ViewController` file or `appDelegate`. However the following code;

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Back")!           
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

But the result of this was far more weird, the image becomes stretched.

Can anyone help me out on why this is happening or give an alternate method to change the back icon in the `UINavigationBar` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  let backImage = UIImage(named: "back_button_name")
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImage?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (backImage?.size.width)!-1, 0, 0)), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_left")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
```